# Insert .html file on WordPress Post

Tags: html, wordpress

I have this .html (https://techstart.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/index-1.html) and i want to insert it on my WordPress Post but I don't want to be as a link. And to show directly on the posting page.

Is this any solution to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use an iframe to do that.

You can use Wordpress editor's HTML block and add soemthing like this:

```
<iframe src="https://techstart.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/index-1.html"></iframe>
```

and add your desired width, height and other options to tag directly:

```
<iframe src="https://techstart.ro/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/index-1.html" height="300" width="500"></iframe>
```

or with css.
The other option would be using any iframe plugin and then the corresponding shortcode. such as:
[iframe](https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/) or [advanced iframe](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-iframe/)

you can read more on it [here](https://publishpress.com/blog/gutenberg/add-iframes-gutenberg-blocks/) and [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-easily-embed-iframe-code-in-wordpress/).